# CakePHP - Possible to have a select box with multiple fields displayed in the options?

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want the user to be able to choose a restaurant from a dropdown list.  I'm achieving this by the simple:

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'Restaurant', array('multiple'=>false, array('empty' => true)));
```

**The issue I have is:** some restaurants have duplicate names, and I need a way for the user to know which is which.  I'd like to have the ID and/or address within the select options like:

```
<li value='62'>McDonalds (1234 Happy St) - #62</li>
<li value='63'>McDonalds (9876 French Fry Ln) - #63</li>
...etc
```

Is there a way to do this?  I'm obviously capable of doing it w/ normal HTML, but... would be nice to stay in CakePHP.

Thanks ahead of time for any thoughts/suggestions/direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load your restaurants you're actually getting an array like this

```
array (
  ID => NAME,
  ID => NAME
)
```

Basically, it's an associated array with the ID as the key and the display field as the value. So as long as you modify that array via the `find` operation or via normal PHP array iteration, you can achieve your goal.

**EDIT**

So your answer is [CakePHP VirtualFields](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields)

In your model you define it as

```
var $virtualFields = array(    
    'rest_unique_name' => 'CONCAT(Restaurant.first_name, " ", Restaurant.address)'
);
```

In your controller you do this

```
   $opts   = array(
            'fields'    => array('id', 'rest_unique_name')
   );
   $restaurants  = $this->Restaurant->find('list', $opts);
```

Comment: The query works - I tried it in my DB software - but it doesn't populate the dropdown display - the ID still shows as the value, but the dropdown appears empty to the user.  Any thoughts?

Comment: (also - I think the quotes in your concat break the string - so I changed them to double quotes, and it worked)

Comment: Paste the output of the $restaurants array in your question. Also paste your view `set` call.

Comment: @Dave, ah that must be it. I just typed it in there. Will edit my answer

Comment: I didn't mean it actually worked - I meant - the query worked when I changed the quotes - but the dropdown is still empty - sorry for confusion.  The array is actually getting to the view empty :(  Array ( [773] => [774] => [4558] => [775] => [776] =>

Comment: @Dave Looks like you're not getting the result set back. I don't have access to my cake machine right now. Try putting an `as name` after the concat call. Also, look at the mysql log at the bottom of the page and run that query manually. See if it actually gives you results with the name and address concatenated. I'm 100% sure this is the way to go, I just can't verify the exact code right now.

Comment: Odd - when I add 'Restaurant.name' at the end (as the 3rd field), I get this:  Array ( [McDonalds] => Array ( [773] => ) [McDonalds] => Array ( [774] => ) ...etc

Comment: @JohnP I actually tried the "... AS name" thing - no luck - I also tried manually running the query that I copied from the mysql dump at the bottom of the page - it works fine manually - I get the concatenated field.

Comment: @JohnP I completely understand your answer - it makes sense.  Just not sure why I'm not getting anything but the ID through to the view.  Does whatever field it returns have to be mentioned in the model or something?

Comment: @Dave, no you should only give 2 fields. Anyway, found the problem. When you do a mysql expression it falls out of the `list` find call. It only works with `all`. A workaround for this is the use `vrtualFields`. Updating my answer with a fix

Comment: @JohnP Awesome!  Virtual Fields were the answer!  I think your answer in it's current form might be confusing for future people looking for this answer, but it works for me!  Thanks a lot!  @anyone who wants details:  [CLICK HERE for CAKE VIRTUAL FIELDS](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields) - they're exactly what you need